# Firebase ignoring security rules when using secret

Tags: firebase

I am attempting to apply some security rules to our firebase instance, but I do not seem to be able to get calls from iOS to respect them. I started with a simple test that verifies authentication (should succeed), and then attempts to write an undefined value to the root (should fail).

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": 
  {
    //Default read and write access to authenticated users only
    ".read" : "auth != null",
    ".write" : "auth != null",

    //Prevent undefined child variables
    "$undef" : { ".validate" : false  }
  }
}
```

Login:

```
- (void)authenticate
{
    [_dataRef authWithCredential:SECURITY_CREDENTIAL //Firebase Secret JSON token
     withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, id data){}
     withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {
          //If the authentication becomes invalid, re-authenticate
          [self authenticate];
     }];
}
```

Write test:

```
[[[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:ROOT_URL] childByAppendingPath:CHILD_PATH] setValue:VALUE];
```

Now what I cant seem to figure out is why the simulator correctly fails to write this value, but iOS ignores the validation and writes the data.

Also upon further testing I ran into a second issue that spawned from this one. If I change the credential I use to authenticate to something that is not a valid firebase secret token, iOS will correctly fail auth, but the simulator with authenticate as long as I pass it any string. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using the Firebase's secret, which isn't a JWT but the shared secret that your trusted server should use to sign a JWT. Currently it's possible to sign in using the secret but it should never be distributed with your clients, and as you're observing it provides admin privileges so bypasses all security rules and validation.

If you already have a user authentication system set up on your own trusted server, you can use one of the [token generator libraries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries) to directly integrate that with Firebase. You could also generate a one-off for testing purposes using one of those, but it's not recommended to distribute that with the client either (anyone could inspect the distributed package and find it if they look hard enough).

Lastly, you could use the Firebase's login service: [Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) to manage users from different providers, including a number of OAuth providers, email/password, and anonymous login.

Comment: And here is the specific section of documentation that [talks about secrets](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-rest-server-authentication), to supplement Chris's answer.

Comment: It'd be nice if this was referenced somewhere on https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-security.html -- just spent a chunk of time wondering why my security and validation rules weren't working :P